# Angularjs $cookies still expiring on refresh even with {expires: } set in options param?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies

I'm currently working on an angular app that needs to track sessions. I'm trying to accomplish this using the $cookies service in angular 1.4+, I'm specifically using 1.4.9 in my application.

The issue is when I login as a user I set my cookies after a successful login as such:

```
var cookieArray = {session_id: sessID, token_access: accessToken};
$cookies.put('my_session', cookieArray, {expires: new Date(2016,6, 30)});
```

After logging in and I check my cookies in chrome it shows the cookie with the proper created and expires dates, in this case expires is July 30th 2016. However, when I refresh the page that cookie still gets deleted. I've done some reading and it seems that setting the expires property is supposed to fix this problem. I've gone through the app and can't find anywhere else in the code where cookies have been touched so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! For anyone else having similar issues I figured I'd share what I found.

First off in this case, since I was saving a full object as a cookie make sure to use the $cookies.putObject() function instead of just $cookies.put(). This will make sure the cookie gets stored properly and doesn't get removed from the browser on refresh even though it says expires: .

Secondly make sure you retrieve the cookie as $cookies.getObject('key') before you check for a proper session.

Hope this helps anyone who was having issues w/ $cookies.put()